# How to save list of arrays in dataframe

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe

Can someone help me if there is solution how to save list of arrays in **Python** in dataframe but this input(list of arrays) changes in cycle so that I need to every array store as new dataframe. Here is the example:

If my input seems look like this:

```
[array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [1, 2, 3]]), array([[3, 4, 5],
       [ 3,  4,  5]])]
```

I need output as dataframes like this:

| 1. column | 2. column | 3. column |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |

| 1. column | 2. column | 3. column |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 4 | 5 |
| 3 | 4 | 5 |

but this is only for first iteration in cycle so when the second iteration start I get new data e.g.

```
[array([[ 6,  7,  8],
       [6, 7, 8]]), array([[9, 10, 11],
       [ 9,  10,  11]])]
```

so I need to update my dataframe first array append to first dataframe and the second array to the second dataframe so the updated table should look like this:

| 1. column | 2. column | 3. column |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 6 | 7 | 8 |
| 6 | 7 | 8 |

| 1. column | 2. column | 3. column |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 4 | 5 |
| 3 | 4 | 5 |
| 9 | 10 | 11 |
| 9 | 10 | 11 |

Is there any way how to make this ?

Answer (score 1):

simply make an data frame out of the sub array, then append it to your main dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
data = [array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [1, 2, 3]]), array([[3, 4, 5],
       [ 3,  4,  5]])]

df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [], "B": [], "C": []})

for arr in data:
    subdf = pd.DataFrame(arr, ["A","B","C"])
    df = df.append(subdf)
```

this returns:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 4 | 5 |
| 3 | 4 | 5 |

Comment: Yes but I need these Arrays to save as different dataframes because after the cycle I need to make graphs one graph for first dataframe and the second graph for the second dataframe

Comment: @Sker you can pretty simply nest this process in a loop that runs for each cycle, and return the cycle's dataframe